# update center in k-means use cosine similarity

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, trigonometry

I have a problem with updating centers in k-means.
my data are like bellow:

```
  1 0 5 6 2 3 5 7
  2 5 0 8 6 1 0 5 . . .
  2 5 6 4 2 1 0 8
         .
         .
```

i need to process rows by rows(example:one row is the center). I calculated clusters with cosine similarity. Now I want to update center of each cluster.but i don`t know how can I do that.please help me.
(each row is contained the number of iteration of different words in a document.)
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is an algorithm which can use cosine metric, known as spherical k-means.

For more information, see

http://www.cs.gsu.edu/~wkim/index_files/papers/refinehd.pdf
http://nirmalthapa.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/spherical-k-means-clustering-algorithm/

Answer (score 1):

**k-means is designed for Euclidean disance, not for other metrics**.

While at first it appears as if you can easily use any other distance function, the problem actually is the *mean* function.

For Euclidean distance, the arithmetic mean will minimize variance and this way ensure termination of the algorithm. For Manhattan distance you can use the medoid instead (see k-medoids clustering).

But if you throw in arbitrary other distance functions, k-means may run into infinite loops (i.e. stop converging). So be careful when using other distances, and consider going to more advanced/modern algorithms than k-means.

Comment: thanks,so how should I use euclidean distance for such a input data?

Comment: just do it. There are not many different ways to compute euclidean distance.

Comment: Why does it matter what distance metric is used, as long as it satisfies the triangle inequality? Also, are you saying that using the cosine distance in k-means yields no convergence? (I am asking about cosine distance specifically). Thanks!

Comment: K-means does not require the triangle inequality. It needs the **mean** function to optimize the same criterion as the minimum-distance assignment. For proper k-means, both minimize the **sum-of-squares**, i.e. variance. Minimization of distance is just a "coincidence" as squared euclidean = variance contribution.